# Обновление свойства 1С Битрикс при обновлении

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь в Битриксе в init.php сделать функцию чтобы обновляла свойство в зависимости от наличия товара. Складской учет отключен.

```js
<?
AddEventHandler('catalog', 'OnProductUpdate', ['MyClass', 'OnProductUpdateHandler']);
class MyClass
{   
 function OnProductUpdateHandler($id, $arFields)
 {
  $arLoadProductArray = $arFields['QUANTITY'] > 0 ? Array("IN_STOCK" => "Y") : Array("IN_STOCK" => "N");
  CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($id, false, $arLoadProductArray);
 }       
}
?>
```

В общем при обновлении товара вызывается функция, которая принимает два аргумента: id и массив. Затем я проверяю количество (надеюсь правильно), и ставлю свойству с кодом IN_STOCK соответствие. Затем применяю эти свойства. Вроде по документации прочитал - сделал, но не работает ))))
Скорее всего я не правильно обращаюсь к количеству товара. Свойство "QUANTITY" по-моему не относится к торговому каталогу. Как его правильно указать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$arFields['QUANTITY'] действительно отвечает за количество товара. Но для верности лучше сделать так `$arLoadProductArray = intval($arFields['QUANTITY']) > 0 ? Array("IN_STOCK" => "Y") : Array("IN_STOCK" => "N");`
Скорее всего ты неправильно выставляешь VALUE свойства. какого типа у тебя свойство IN_STOCK? Список, Строка?

Если это список - возможно пригодится код такого вида:

```
$prop["IN_STOCK"] = array('VALUE_ENUM_ID'=> <ID>);
CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($el_id, $iblock_id, $prop);
```

Используй VALUE_ENUM_ID Для того чтобы установить верное значение для Типа Список. найти его можно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В конце концов ты легко можешь вычислить какая из этих строк тебя подводит проставив значения вручную.